# Fix a ComboBox to an Image

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm using an `Image` with a `ComboBox` in my C# WPF application.

I want the `ComboBox` fixed in top/right corner of `Image` (not the grid containing both). Actually these two elements are in a grid.

It's hard for me to clearly explain what I want, there is pictures to help me.

What I want:

[image: resizeOK]

What I have:

[image: resizeNOK]

How can I write my `ComboxBox` to achive this ?

```
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="VideoControl" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListCameraDevices" Style="{StaticResource  {x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="auto"                  
              Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White"
              BorderThickness="0"/>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaaty's answer is mostly right but the column definitions are not needed. You simply need to ensure the Image has it's Stretch property set to 'Uniform' so that it sizes the inner grid correctly.

Here's a simplified version:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="https://a2ua.com/awesome/awesome-004.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: My bad, it works good, i forgotten to remove another image from that Grid... Now it's perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding the Image and ComboBox inside their own grid (Inside the other Grid), and have them overlap in the same Grid Column set out by the ColumnDefinition.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition />
             <ColumnDefinition />
         </Grid.ColumDefinitions>
         <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="VideoControl"      FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
         <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListCameraDevices" Style="{StaticResource   {x:Static ToolBar.ComboBoxStyleKey}}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="auto"                  
          Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="White"
          BorderThickness="0"/>
    </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Or maybe just putting them inside their own Grid still, and just setting the ZIndex of the ComboBox to appear ontop.

[EDIT]:

Created a test project, does pretty much what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've try your solution but there is not visible change. The ComboBox is still on the grid's corner. When I resize the grid (with a GridSplitter) the combox get out from the image. Is there a way to place the ComboxBox "inside" the image ?

Comment: It's work, I took the ibebbs's solution (shortest) but thank you